# iteration with generator expression works differently than expected

Tags: python, list, generator-expression

I would expect the removal to work in the same way and the list to be the same after the two iterations that remove elements, but it is not so.
I suspect that modifying the list I am iterating on may be the cause but was also expecting that somehow this would be managed safely by the language.
Can someone help me understand what happens, why the results are different?

```
my_list = list(range(10))
to_remove_l =    [ x for x in my_list if x%3 == 0]
to_remove_genex = (x for x in my_list if x%3 == 0)

print(f"id: {id(my_list)}")
print(my_list)

removed = []
for e in to_remove_l:
    print(f"removing: {e}")
    my_list.remove(e)
    removed.append(e)
print(my_list)

my_list.extend(removed)
print(f"id: {id(my_list)}")
print(my_list)
to_remove_genex = (x for x in my_list if x%3 == 0)
for e in to_remove_genex:
    print(f"removing: {e}")
    my_list.remove(e)
print(my_list)
```

the output is

```
id: 1822749490560
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
removing: 0
removing: 3
removing: 6
removing: 9
[1, 2, 4, 5, 7, 8]
id: 1822749490560
[1, 2, 4, 5, 7, 8, 0, 3, 6, 9]
removing: 0
removing: 6
[1, 2, 4, 5, 7, 8, 3, 9]
```

Comment: The list comprehension calculates its entire result up front, using the unmodified, original list.  The generator expression version calculates values as you iterate over it - every time you delete an element from the list, that means that there is an element that the generator won't examine, because it is now below the generator's current index.

Comment: Ultimately this is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6260089/strange-result-when-removing-item-from-a-list-while-iterating-over-it-in-python, but only after you understand that a generator expression is a fancy way to encapsulate a loop.

Comment: Essentially the problem seen in the many duplicates of [How to remove items from a list while iterating?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1207406/364696), with extra steps.

Comment: @mkrieger1: The OP does seem to understand that they are modifying the `list` while iterating over it, so I think we can safely use your dupe.

Comment: FWIW, the question title could be more specific. See [ask] for tips on that. Maybe something like "Why does a generator skip items when used to remove from a list?" I dropped the word "expression" because functionally, it's not important how you create it, any generator would work the same, but on the other hand it's visually similar to a list comp, so you do you.

Comment: From the question is clear that I am aware of the risk of modifying lists you are iterating over but that I expected generators to be safer, so this question does not seem to me to be a duplicate of those about modifying the list you're iterating over.
Thanks to @jasonharper that provided an answee in his comment. 
I think that too easily SO marks questions as duplicate or somehow wrong when they aren't, this also applies to the comment about making the title of this question more specific. Since some years SO has become disappointing in this respect.

Comment: Some comments above assume that I be aware of the internals of generators. 
Is one who asks a question expected to know the internals? Is that expectation reasonable?